# php: how to get timestamp of 2 weeks later day

Tags: php, timestamp

I'm using `strtotime("next week")` to get the next week's timestamp. now i need to get the timestamp of 'next week' of 'next week', i.e. 2 weeks later.

can anybody plz help...

-venkat nehatha

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

`'Next 2 Week: '.strtotime('+2 week');`

Comment: Welcome !! I think if that is your answer you should accept it :)

Answer (score 1):

I found `strtotime("+2 week")`